# PHP - How to pass value in database to another page when clicked

Tags: php, html, mysql

how can I pass this value which data is in database. I want to pass the value from another page by textbox. how can I do it?

here is my database 
[image]

and I want to pass the `Value` on the textbox from another page how can I do that?

here is my code

```
include("topupcard.php";)

<td>
      <?php echo htmlentities($row['value']);?>
   </td>

    <button class="btn btn-success mr-4"><a href="generatecode.php">Generate QR Code</a></button>
```

and to pass the data to another page.

```
<input type="text" value="$row['value']" name="id">
```

right now, it is not working nothing is being passed. 
also, i dont know if I'll use Session or not, help thanks.

so the output should be **200** or **1000** is displayed on the other page when i click the button.

Comment: you could put the value as a http URL argument 'generatecode.php?value=X' or in the session information, or as a cookie. All depending on the sensitivity. Check OWASP docs for security guidance.

Comment: how can i put it sir? can you please provide me specific code thank you so much sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using @danblack's explanation you can

Option 1 (not a safe method if this involves transactions):

```
<a href="generatecode.php?value=<?php echo htmlentities($row['value']); ?>">
```

then on the other page

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $_GET['value']; ?>" name="id">
```

Option 2 :

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['value'] = $row['value'];
```

then on the other page

```
session_start();
$value = $_SESSION['value'];
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" name="id">
```

Comment: hello value `1000` is the only value showing even i clicked on `200` the value is still `1000` i used option 2

Comment: "other page" on option 1 looks like a non-persistent cross-site scripting vulnerability. Thanks for the writeup @vic-zapico